# Using $(this) in setTimeout();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set timeouts dynamically in jQuery. The dynamically set timeout functions need to use $("this"), but I can't seem to get it working.

An exmple:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).attr('data-content')
    setTimeout("$(this).html('"+content+"')",$(this).attr('data-delay'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmhmQ/

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: As always: Pass a function (closure), not a string. That ensures that everything is in scope and is easier to read, debug, etc.

Comment: never use `setTimeout("...")`, but rather `setTimeout(function(){...})`!

Comment: If you want to play with `data-` then shouldn't you be using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)?

Comment: @Quentin Is there a difference in $.attr('data') and $.data(), except the length?

Comment: @Quentin. Nope, `data()` use cache. `attr(data-...`) use the HTML-5 attributes.

Comment: @ONOZ. There is a lot! read the docs of `data`

Comment: Quote: *As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).attr('data-content'),
        $this = $(this); // here $this keeps the reference of $(this)
    setTimeout(function() {

      // within this funciton you can't get the $(this) because
      // $(this) resides within in the scope of .each() function i.e $(this)
      // is an asset of .each() not setTimeout()
      // so to get $(this) here, we store it within a variable (here: $this) 
      // and then using it

        $this.html(content);
    }, $this.attr('data-delay'));
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/qmhmQ/6/)**

Comment: An explanation as to what you changed and why would make this a decent answer. A blob of code doesn't really help anybody learn anything.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for  you suggestion, I try to explain the code, please see and make edit if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look like this:

1. pass a function instead of a string.
   Explanation:
   When passing a string to setTimeout you get problems, because it runs in a different scope than you original one, and thus you get errors.
2. use the jQuery `data()`method

   ```
   $("div").each(function(){
        var content = $(this).attr('data-content'),
            $el = $(this),
            setContent = function(){
               $el.html(content);
            }
        setTimeout(setContent,$el.data('delay'));
   });​
   ```

You can assign a function to a variable and pass that variable as parameter to setTimeout, this is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 3):

Use closures ([some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff696765.aspx)).

Using strings with `setTimeout` is not a good idea. Also beware `this`, since it can change its context ([ie. call-site](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#call-site)) if used inside a closure.

If using data attributes you can use the jQuery data function.

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var instance = $(this);
  var content = instance.data('content');
  var method = function() {
    instance.html(content);
  };
  setTimeout(method, instance.data('delay'));
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-content="fus" data-delay="1000"></div>
<div data-content="ro" data-delay="2000"></div>
<div data-content="dah" data-delay="5000"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about closures? I've never seen them before.

Comment: I've added some tutorial links

Answer (score 2):

I am just expanding answer one above,

1. Use class or id to refer div in JavaScript. This will avoid further tag name conflicts in the page.

So your updated HTML is,

```
<div data-content="fus" data-delay="1000" class="dv"></div>
<div data-content="ro" data-delay="2000" class="dv"></div>
<div data-content="dah" data-delay="5000" class="dv"></div>​
```

Now your updated JavaScript code is,

```
$(".dv").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).attr('data-content'),
    $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.html(content);
    }, $this.attr('data-delay'));
});​
```

Where main line is

> $this = $(this);

Where we are assigning the current element to our variable used in the setTimeout function.

Please refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qmhmQ/7/)

Comment: Can I use a css selector like div[data-content^=] to avoid having to add a class on each div?

Comment: Sorry for delay, Yes you can use selector also. Please refer link here http://jsfiddle.net/qmhmQ/9/

Answer (score 1):

Take $(this) out of settimeout and save that in local variable say 'self' just after *$("div").each(function(){* this line

```
var self=$(this);
```

and use that *self* further.

Comment: Doesn't the eval of the string passed to setTimeout break scope, so that won't work?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems like a good compromise of whitespace, readability and revealing intention.

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var element = $(this)
    var content = element.attr('data-content')
    var delayms = element.attr('data-delay')
    var action = function() { element.html(content) }

    setTimeout(action, delayms)
})
```

​
SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/wilmoore/LSs6g/